# Extract an array from array based on the filter/like partial string

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an Array of Numbers

```
var arrayA = [65432000,65432001,65431002,65431222,65430123,65430124,65430125]
```

I want to filter based on first five digits and return as array of filtered elements. I.e, if I pass 65432 is my filter criteria it should return

```
var resultArray = [65432000,65432001]
```

If 65430 then

```
var resultArray = [65430123,65430124,65430125]
```

if 65431 then

```
var resultArray = [65431002,65431222]
```

I should not loose any values in `arrayA`.

How to get this by using javascript?

Comment: What type is the data in your array?

Comment: Datatype is Number . Edited the question Thankyou

Comment: I updated my answer with this new information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code has a problem, the data type is incorrect. If you meant for the items to be `number` you cannot use `-`.

That said, assuming the correct data type is `number`, you can create a new array that filters the existing one based on the condition `startsWith(prefix)`.

```
var arrayA = [65432000,65432001,65431002,65431222,65430123,65430124,65430125];

function filter(prefix) {
    return arrayA.filter(function (item) {
       return item.toString().startsWith(prefix.toString());
  })
}

var res = filter(65430);
console.log(res); //[65430123, 65430124, 65430125]
```